# Web Globalization - Anything New in VS2013?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, globalization, visual-studio-2013

For a new Asp.Net MVC web site that need to support Globalization (languages, right-to-left/left-to-right, currencies, dates...): Is there anything new in VS 2013 that makes it a better tool for this over VS 2012?

Comment: See [What's New in Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063.aspx). The stuff you're interested in are either in (ASP).NET or more specific libraries, I don't expect any changes there with this relatively minor release of VS2013.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I've read this and I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: The point is all of the current tool improvements have no specific internationalization or globalization improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, changes in asp.net focus more on the development experience not internationalization improvements. The complete list of features for .net can be found here **http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes#TOC14**

Comment: I have seen this product used for an extremely large multi language product, managing translation process http://www.redpin.eu/index.html